# Инструмент для мониторинга Memcache

Tags: memcache, php

Добрый день.

Я создаю ключ и значение Memcache в php. А есть ли какой-то инструмент, чтоб увидеть вживую, какие значения сейчас в памяти?

В MemcacheAdmin я такого не нашёл.
Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[phpMemAdmin](https://github.com/clickalicious/phpMemAdmin). Недавно [в дайджасте на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/zfort/blog/250075/) упоминался этот инструмент с web-интерфейсом.